# how to include a readme file electron?

Tags: electron-packager

How can I add a file, like README.md, into the root directory of a electron application?
I'm using `electron-packager`, so I'd like to stick with that.

- The file sits in my project root, and contains the release notes. I want the users to also see the exact same file in the program directory.

Note - I do NOT want to:

- add the file into a subdirectory like resources
- access the file from inside the application

[image]